# Help in Google Sheets with cell references

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

In the image above, I am attempting to take the name in line 3, and make that part of the command of the SUMIF, so to reference the tab of that name in the same sheet.

The command I have is using such right now, du eot not being able to replace the name with a reference to the cell in line 3:

=SUMIFS('John Smith'!$G$5:$G,'John Smith'!$A$5:$A,$A$3,'John Smith'!$A$5:$A,$B$3,'John Smith'!$D$5:$D,$A5)

No matter what Ive tried, I cannot seem to reference as part of the command the cell with the name.

Here is what I incision this as a command, but doesn't work:

(John Smith is in cell D3 as an example)

=SUMIFS(D3!$G$5:$G,D3!$A$5:$A,$A$3,D3!$A$5:$A,$B$3,D3!$D$5:$D,$A5)

Any help would be appreciated, and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the INDIRECT function. It serves exactly the case you are dealing with. Instead of making reference to `D3!$G$5`, for example, use `INDIRECT(D3 & "!G5")`.